# How to create an array with null values after first item with custom value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have

```
a = [2,8,7,8,9]

b = 55
```

I want to create an array with the same length of array 'a' with first item 'b' and rest of them `null`

like this:

```
c = [55, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
var a = [2,8,7,8,9];
var b = 55;

a.map((e, i) => (i == 0) ? b : null);
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel like most of these replies are verbose and use old techniques. Here's an easy to read one liner:

```
let c = [b, ...new Array(a.length - 1).fill(null)]
```

```js
const a = [2, 8, 7, 8, 9]
const b = 55

let c = [b, ...new Array(a.length - 1).fill(null)]

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Array.prototype.from` and pass the new `length` of the array as length of `a` subtracted by 1 and map the other items to `null` in the mapping function argument

Then using the spread syntax `...` combine the `null` elements of the generated array with `b`:

```js
const a = [2,8,7,8,9]

const b = 55

const c = [b, ...Array.from({length: a.length - 1}, () => null)]
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Follows an full working example:

```js
var a = [2,8,7,8,9]
var b = 55
var c = a.map(value => null);
c[0] = b;
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const a = [2, 8, 7, 8, 9]
const b = 55

const c = []
c.length = a.length
c.fill(null)
c[0] = b

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `c = a.map((_, i) => i === 0 ? b : null)`

- It only uses one pass over the array
- It only creates one additional array (the one you assign to `c`)
- It doesn't rely on mutative methods
- It's still only one line long

You can make it work for multiple indicies with a `Map` or a plain object:

```js
const differentValues = {
  0: 33,
  3: 99
}

const c = a.map((_, i) => i in differentValues ? differentValues[i] : null)
// [33,8,7,99,9]
```